# "...Это так громко восхваляют радость жизни птицы"?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Первые глотки воздуха просто ударяют в лёгкие, и, пока приходишь в
>   себя, обнаруживаешь, что это не звон стоит в ушах – **это так громко
>   восхваляют радость жизни птицы.**

Меня что-то смутило в восхвалении радости жизни... Понятно, что автор пожелал уйти от птиц воспевающих (далее будет немало глаголов, связанных с пением), но - восхвалять радость?

---

О. Нашла у Элен Рерих, но неспроста же я задалась вопросом ["Елены Рерих и Блаватская - психи, или Кто такие эзотерические философы?"](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2413799-eleny-rerih-i-blavatskaja-psihi-ili-kto-takie-ezotericheskie-filosofy.html#answer7115214)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: - это птицы так громко радуются жизни своим пением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Радость жизни** — это тема птичьих песен. Они поют хвалебные песни о радости жизни, то есть восхваляют радость жизни.

Это сочетание надо воспринимать как единое целое, не деля его на отдельные слова.

*Восхвалять радость* — это действительно звучит странно.